# How fast can an Android camera flash turn on/off?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to turn the LED flash for the camera of an Android smartphone very fast on/off, and I was wondering if anyone knows about hardware/OS limitation specifications?

The flash light software I've used so far on my Samsung GT s7580 seemed to have pretty big latency when I tried to switch on and off, and the application I want to make needs to keep the light open for a 10th of a second...

Am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: What do you mean by big latency? How do you turn it on/off now? It could depend on the manufacturer of the hardware. After all for a flash you have to charge a condensator before somewhere. Anyway my guess is that your app is designed to drown the battery as fast as possible. ;)

Comment: I was using a flashlight app from Google play called "Flash Light Torch".

Comment: Latency was up to 1 second. I must check the app from @kamituel's response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested [LED Strobe app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easylabs.strobe&hl=en) from the Google play, and at its fastest setting it's giving me a pretty rapid on/off cycle. I'd say it's close to 10 fps. Some flashes are bright, some are dimmer (but still visible) - it could be related to the power inefficiencies for such a fast cycle.

Anyway, I don't think you can guarantee 10 fps, it'd be dependent on any of the: phone model, LED module, power connection to the LED, battery power level. In my case, I tested it on Moto X 1st gen.

Comment: this is not an answer, this should be a comment!

Comment: Well, this answer shows that there is no software (OS) limitation to it, I will simply approve it, and move on to a different stackexchange site for the hardware part. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I was wondering the same thing, and I got a time that varied between about 2.5 and 3 seconds for 50 on/off cycles in a Samsung Galaxy Ace 3 GT-S7275Y
I used the deprecated Camera object and the code I used is pasted below:

```
Camera cam;
Camera.Parameters p;


public void turnOnFlashLight() {
    if (cam != null) {
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        cam.setParameters(p);
    }

}

public void turnOffFlashLight() {
    if (cam != null) {
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
        cam.setParameters(p);
    }
}

public void prepareCamera() {
    if (cam == null) {
        try {
            cam = Camera.open();
            p = cam.getParameters();
            if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
                p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                cam.setParameters(p);
                cam.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Exception throws in turning on flashlight.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

public void flashSpeedTest(View v) {
    prepareCamera();
    long startTm = System.nanoTime();
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; ++x) {
        if (x % 2 == 0)
            turnOnFlashLight();
        else
            turnOffFlashLight();
    }
    long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - startTm;
    Misc.showMessage(this, String.format("%.3f seconds", elapsed/1e9));
}
```